# async await setstate and returning promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

1) I am trying to better understand `async await`. I had a notion that setting `setState` in the `await .then(//setState)` function would take care of the asynchronous nature of `setState`, but this doesn't seem to be true after running some tests.

```
constructor(){
   this.state = { msg: 'ZERO' }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setter();
    this.setState({ msg: 'TWO' });

    console.log('AFTER', this.state.msg) //Logs TWO
}

setter = () => {
    this.setState({ msg: 'ONE' }, () => console.log('INSIDE', this.state.msg)); //Logs ONE
    console.log('BOTTOM', this.state.msg) //Logs ZERO
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

The log in `setter()` `BOTTOM` shows `ZERO` and this demonstrates the asynchronous nature of `setState`. Even though the state is being set to `ONE` before the log, it shows the default value `ZERO`. The part I don't understand is, when the Promise returns and the `setState` happens again after `await this.setter()`, the log `AFTER` will show `TWO`. Shouldn't this be `ONE`, since the `setState` in `setter` was from `await` then the `setState` after is not wrapped in promise or await, but `AFTER` log still shows correct value. Why??

2) My other Question regarding async await is the return of promises. When I don't return `Promise.resolve()` it will show an error, `uncaught promise, cannot read property of then`. However, I have a `onSubmit` function that applies await on a passed in prop function that does not return `Promise.resolve()` but the error doesnt show.

//COMPONENT A

```
onSubmit = async () => {
    await this.props.passedInFunction(1);
}
```

//COMPONENT B

```
passedInFunction = (num) => this.setState({value: num});
```

As you can see, the `passedInFunction` from `COMPONENT B` is not returning a `Promise.resolve` but for some reason, in my application when the function gets called in `COMPONENT A` that `uncaught promise error doesn't show.

EDIT: Forgot to add `await` in front of the `passedInFunction`

Comment: Yes, but as shown in my first example, when I did not return `Promise.resolve()` it threw the uncaught promise error. But in the second example, it does not. WHy?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour depends on how you are using async await.

One thing to note is that await works inside an async function. Secondly, if you use await to wait for a function that is not asynchronous.
According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> If the value is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved
>   Promise, and waits for it.

So you don't need to return `Promise.resolve()` from within `setter` method and that

```
onSubmit = async () => {
    await this.props.passedInFunction(1);
}
```

and

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setter();
    this.setState({ msg: 'TWO' });

    console.log('AFTER', this.state.msg) //Logs TWO
}
```

will both work without errors.

> Now coming to the point on why  `console.log('AFTER', this.state.msg)`
>   returns TWO.

setState is asynchronous and it doesn't guarantee that the update will be visible immediately but it also doesn't tell you that the update will never be visible immediately.

In your case, the setState call is the last one in componentDidUpdate and there is not batching that will take place and hence it updates immediately. Saying that, there is no gurantee that in future you write some code and this behaviour no longer holds true.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/zwy8v3x264)

Comment: `if you use await to wait for a function that is not asynchronous in nature, await will behave as if the function returns a promise` is a bit misleading. `await` is applied on the result of the expression on its right hand side, it does not wait for a function. That result is either a Promise or not, if it is Promise it waits until that Promise is not pending anymore, if it is not a Promise then the value is implicitly converted to a resolved Promise. The `asnyc` keyword  guarantees that the returned value is a Promise and allows the usage of `await` in it.

Comment: @shubham khatri `"If the value is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved Promise, and waits for it."` where is this from? Can . you please share link

Comment: @henhen,Its from MDN docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await